# Random background video on page load with html/js

Tags: javascript, html, random, video, background

Is worked my way through all responses but i just can't get my head around how to make this work.
I want to have a selection of 4 background videos which random on load.
So far, this is what i got.

```js
const possibleVideos = ["/_1/video/bgvid3.mp4", "/_1/video/bgvid2.mp4"];
const randomVideo = possibleVideos[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleVideos.length)];
document.querySelector('video.background-video').src = randomVideo;
```

```html
<video id="background-video" disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload" autoplay loop muted poster="">
        <source src="/_1/video/bgvid3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I understand how the parts work but i dont understand how to connect them.

Comment: Well you are trying to set the `src` of `'video.my-video'` which doesn't exist. Your console is telling you what's wrong, open it

Comment: sorry, i got confused with all the testfiles i already created... still not working

Comment: Even after the edit, `'video.background-video'` does not exist. Same error in the console

Comment: right, thats why im so confused, how do i connect the script with the tag?

Comment: You are querying a class `".background-video"` but your element has an ID `"#background-video"`

Comment: thank you, i changed to an id selector but the video is still not showing

Comment: You're setting the `src=` attribute of the `<video>`  tag, but you need to set the `src=` attribute of the `<source>` tag. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. so the connection is:

document.querySelector('#vid_tag').src = randomVideo;
------>
<source src="" id="vid-tag" type="video/mp4"> or <source id="vid-tag" type="video/mp4"> unfortunatly neither works

Comment: so my question is what should the "src=" in the html code contain?

Answer (score 0):

If your **file paths are correct** then try something like this (study the code as to why it works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="background-video" controls muted>
<source src="none.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>

<script>

const possibleVideos = ["/_1/video/bgvid3.mp4", "/_1/video/bgvid2.mp4"];

//# get a randoom number
//# note: Array length is 2 but Array item1 starts at [0], item2 is at [1]..
const randomNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * (possibleVideos.length-1) )
const randomVideo = possibleVideos[ randomNum ];

//# access the required video tag
const myVid = document.getElementById('background-video');

//# load and play the new "src" file
myVid.src = randomVideo;
myVid.load();
myVid.play();

</script>

</html>
```